# JS Bubble Sorting of a simple array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm doing a JS course foccused on Algarithms problems. Here is a simple exercise that I'm understandig successfully with one exception, that I will explain further.

Here is a solution of the structor on bubble sorting array.

```
console.log(bubbleSort([10, -30, 97, 0, 5]))

function bubbleSort(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < (arr.length - i- 1); j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        const lesser = arr[j + 1]
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
        arr[j] = lesser
      }
    }
  return arr
}
```

It Returns:

[-30, 0, 5, 10, 97] How it should be.

My doubt is:

On this line:

```
   for (let j = 0; j < (arr.length - i- 1); j++) {
```

What is the purpose of this: `arr.length - i` ?
Because when I remove `-i` it works at the same way.

Comment: It reduces the amount of work that the inner loop has to do. The initial passes through the loops push the largest values to the end of the array. Once they're at the end, they don't need to be checked again.

Comment: But why do not the same? in the first for loop made with i?

Comment: on every complete iteration of outer loop the top element placed at correct place.
e.g on first complete outerloop it places lowest element on top. so we no more need to compare it. so to ignore that element the `-i` is there. it will reduce number of iteration.

Comment: It might help you to understand if you add `console.log()` calls to have the code report exactly what it's doing, and what the current state of the array is.